# What fonts are used for "Mathematica" in Wolfram's and our logos?

Tags: discussion, support, design

What font is used for "Mathematica" in our logo?

[image: Mathematica.SE logo]
[image: Mathematica.SE logo cropped]

I thought it might be the italic of the default Mathematica font ([Utopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_%28typeface%29))—

[image]

—and while it looks similar, the logo font has angled vertical strokes on `M`, a serif at the top of `c`, a wider hook at the bottom of `t`, and a thicker horizontal stroke weight.

I tried some online font identification tools but they didn't work.

## What about the Wolfram Mathematica logo?

[image: Wolfram Mathematica logo screenshot]

It seems to use a third font.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jin [mentioned in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=5327164#5327164) during the design phase that the font used in mma.se's logo is [Vollkorn](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Vollkorn), with a [custom kerning](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=5327188#5327188).

Currently, and since about *Mathematica* version 6/7, the main **Wolfram Mathematica** logo is set in Minion Pro Regular/Italic. Before then, a number of different fonts were used, including Palatino, some kind of all-capitals Garamond, Meridien, and, going back to version 1 (1989), Times Italic. To see some of the earlier versions of *Mathematica*'s branding, visit the [Wolfram Scrapbook](http://www.wolfram.com/company/scrapbook/).

In the following picture, first is the OP's original scan, followed by a redrawing showing what Palatino would look like. Then there's this site's font, Vollkorn. And finally, a redrawing using Minion Pro. The Palatino Italic is a bit more like handwriting.

[image: the fontz]

Comment: The original Wolfram logo seems to have a more condensed kerning due to the (R).

Comment: Yes, I can't do kerning... :) Perhaps that's a job for a `Manipulate` one day!

Comment: I added info on our logo's font into your answer and deleted mine, since  you have visual examples.

Comment: @rm-rf Good idea. I owe you a point... :)